# Ansible executing playbook boto missing

Tags: ansible, boto

When running the ansible playbook it says the following message

> FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "boto required for this module"}

I have specified the python interpreter in the ansible-playbook as follows:

```
  hosts: aws
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
```

and when I check the pip3 module, it is installed.

```
$ pip3 list
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
apturl (0.5.2)
asn1crypto (0.24.0)
boto (2.49.0)
boto3 (1.9.88)
botocore (1.12.92)
```

Comment: You'll need to provide us with the path of your `pip3`, because it sounds like there are multiple pythons in your story, and `/usr/bin/python3` does not appear to have boto

Comment: you mean where the python3 install its packages?
in the /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages i have boto there too 

but in lib i do have multiple pythons, the 2.7, 3, 3.6 and 3.7

Comment: I mean what is the output of `which pip3`, and also just for clarity, we are talking about the `python3` binary on those "aws" hosts, right? And you said there is a 3.6 and 3.7 library, so which is `python3` pointing at? Come on, help us to help you

Comment: I guess you try to run aws-related module on `aws` hosts, but check Python on your localhost.

Comment: the path is /usr/bin/pip3 for the command which pip3
using ansible ec2 to terminate the instance via state: absent

Comment: Any further update on that? I'm facing the same issue